# is France supported by paypal rest-api for live transactions paypal-android-sdk

Tags: android, rest, paypal, transactions, live

after setting CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT  to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION and setting live credentials, all my payments with valid credit card and verified account are failed

I have this error UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT when I pay with credit card

then, I am wondering if france is supported by the rest api of paypal or not

because even if I use a france account I have this :

[image]

how to resolve this issue

Comment: no they doesn't say that

Comment: see this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

Comment: only direct credit card payment is limited on those countries, no ?

Comment: I think so, I'm trying to figure out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct Credit Card payments from the mobile SDKs are not supported in France at this time (see [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments)).  You are able to accept PayPal payments, however.  It's easy to disable credit card support in the SDK with [PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PaymentActivity.html#EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD).